# Retrieve HTML code from controller

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to retrieve the html code generated from **controller A** within **controller B**?

### Controller A

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @Route("/{user_id}/cart", name="user_cart")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showCartAction($user_id)
{

    $cart = $this->getCartManager()
        ->getUserCart($user_id);

    return array(
        'cart'=> cart
    );

}
```

### Controller B

```
/**
 *
 *
 * @Route("/html", name="htmlGenerated")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showHTMLAction()
{
    $user_id = 3;

    $html = //How to obtain the html generated by Controller A with UserId = 3 ????
//...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [forward](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) the request in Controller B

```
public function showHTMLAction()
{
    $user_id = 3;

    $html = $this->forward('AcmeDemoBundle:ControllerB:showCardAction', array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
    ))->getContent();        
}
```

Even though this should work perfectly fine, I would actually advise you to [embed the controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in your template instead.